# Styling all JButtons at once

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, look-and-feel

When setting styles for `JButton` components. Is there a way to set the style for multiple buttons at once if they have the same style or do I need to set it each separately?

Answer (score 0):

With a loop for, you can set the style. Example:

```
JButton[] button;
for(i=0; i<button.length; i++){
    button[i] = new JButton[];
    String nameButton = "Button" +i;
    button[i].setText(nameButton);
    button[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, nice! I was thinking of a loop but I thought there might be an official way.

Comment: *"I thought there might be an official way"* There is. Adjust the [**look** and feel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/look-and-feel)..